# How to extend arch linux partition without Gparted

Tags: partitioning, arch-linux, gparted

I have arch-linux installed on `dev/sda8`. I have about 39 GB of unallocated space just above `dev/sda8`. I want to move the same below sda8 so I can extend my linux parttion. I tried Gparted from linux 16.04 live disk. but it fails saying

> e2fsck is old, get a newer version of e2fsck

Is there any way to extend my linux boot partition by any tool other than Gparted, maybe from arch live iso? Please I need some help from here.

[image: This is my partition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GParted also has a live CD/USB that you may download from the
[GParted website](https://gparted.org/).

This might also be the safest way to run it.

Comment: does that work without problems like "e2fsck is old"?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it would be ridiculous if they can't make their own live CD work and didn't even test it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a solution myself. Just **use Linux 18.04 live ISO** instead linux 16.04. The partitioning done smooth and fast. From my research, I found out that the Gparted and e2fsck versions on 16.04 ISO is older and doesn't support new filesystem partition formats.